# Section numbering in Beamer ('CambridgeUS' theme)

Tags: beamer, sectioning, numbering

Does anybody know how to make latex put the number for a section presented in header?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\begin{document}

\section{Section a}
\begin{frame}
Test frame
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those themes using the `infolines` outer theme, such as `CambridgeUS`, you can add the following lines to the preamble:

```
\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{section in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\thesection\ \insertsectionhead\hspace*{2ex}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,left]{subsection in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\hspace*{2ex}\insertsubsectionhead
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
```

EDIT: In the following example I defined a `\Switch` command that allows to turn on/off the numbering of the sections in the headline; initially, it is set to `0` (turn off numbering), but redefining it to be `1` will turn on the numbering; the command can be redefined as many times as required:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\newcommand\Switch{0}
\newcommand\SecInHead{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\Switch}{1}}
    {\thesection.}{}}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{section in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\SecInHead\insertsectionhead\hspace*{2ex}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,left]{subsection in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\hspace*{2ex}\insertsubsectionhead
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Test frame with un-numbered section
\end{frame}

\renewcommand\Switch{1}
\section{Section a}
\begin{frame}
Test frame with numbered section
\end{frame}

\renewcommand\Switch{0}
\begin{frame}
Test frame with un-numbered section
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works. Minor change "\thesection." instead of "\thesection" makes exactly that what I want.

Comment: I am sorry very much. There is a bug. Section "0." appeared in title frame. Are there any ideas how to manage with it?

Comment: To place @Gonzalo Medina's piece of code AFTER the title frame is enough to solve the problem with "0." in header on title frame.

Comment: @Andriy Andrusyk: I presume that the undesired number appears for frames not belonging to any section? If this is so, a quick fix would be to redefine \thesection locally for those frames: `{\renewcommand\thesection{}
\begin{frame}
Test frame
\end{frame}
}`. Notice the grouping `{` and `}` braces to keep the redefinition local.

Comment: It partially solves the problem. The last thing is nasty "." in header of the title frame. (I've replaced "\thesection" with "\thesection.":
\usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\thesection.\ \insertsectionhead\hspace*{2ex}
).

Comment: @Andriy Andrusyk: I have an idea for a more definitive solution; I'll let you the result.

Comment: @Andriy Andrusyk: I've updated my answer with a new approach: you can turn on/off the section numbering simply by redefining a command, as the example code illustrates.

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina: Thank you, it works. However, I've found another way to solve problem with "." It is trivial! ) I should just put a line '\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}.}' at the beginning. Then '\renewcommand\thesection{}' before the title frame works correctly.

Comment: @Andriy Andrusyk: the problem with that redefinition is that now the dot will also appear if you label/cross-reference sections, and that might not be desirable.

Answer (score 2):

The solution of @Gonzalo Medina have to be a bit modified. If we want to manage with subsection number too we can modify the code in the following way:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\newcommand\Switch{0}
\newcommand\SecInHead{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\Switch}{1}}
    {\thesection.}{}}
\newcommand\SubSecInHead{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\Switch}{1}}
    {\thesubsection. }{}}
\newcommand\RealSubSecInHead{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\thesubsection}{0}}
    {}{\SecInHead\SubSecInHead}}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{section in head/foot}%
  \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\SecInHead\ \insertsectionhead\hspace*{2ex}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,left]{subsection in head/foot}%
  \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\hspace*{2ex}\RealSubSecInHead\insertsubsectionhead
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Test frame with un-numbered section
\end{frame}

\renewcommand\Switch{1}
\section{Section a}
\begin{frame}
Test frame with numbered section
\end{frame}

\renewcommand\Switch{0}
\begin{frame}
Test frame with un-numbered section
\end{frame}

\renewcommand\Switch{1}
\section{Section a2}
\begin{frame}
Test frame with numbered section again
\end{frame}

\subsection{Subsection a2.1}
\begin{frame}
Test frame with numbered subsection again
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```